# Ownership of custom object record is not allowing user to view related account

Tags: custom-object, sharing, org-wide-defaults

We'd like users who own records for a custom object (Projects) to be able to click from the Project record to view the related account. This works perfectly in opportunities, so I'm wondering why it doesn't work from the custom object Project record.

As an example, logging in as a particular user who owns an opportunity, I'm able to click the account name on the opportunity and I am navigated to the account page. However, if I do the same thing on a project record that the same user owns, I get an "insufficient privileges" error message.

I've verified the object permissions. I've also verified that the user doesn't own either account (to confirm that access to the account from the opportunity wasn't due to account ownership). I'm not sure where else to look.

Any ideas?

Comment: I presume the lookup to Account from Project is a normal lookup field? Is the Project page a standard or Visualforce page?

Comment: The lookup to the Account from Project is a normal lookup field, and the Project page is a VF page. Do you think the VF page could be the issue? I could probably whip up a quick standard page layout to test that out.

Comment: Possibly, could you add the relevant section from the vf page to the question?

Comment: I tested it from a standard page, and I got the same error message. I'll look into copying the relevant section from the VF page (getting some help from a colleague to do this).

Comment: Last obvious things I can think of is around the lookup field, is it read only for the profile of the user or has lookup filters assigned to it? Is there a workflow rule/roll up summary field/apex trigger that could be updating the Account on a project being associated?

Comment: Thank you for your help, @Girbot. I've gathered some more information that seems to address this exact situation. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce uses implicit sharing for opportunities, but does not provide this for custom objects:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sharing_across_objects.htm&language=en_US

To get around this, someone would either have to add the user to the account team, manually share the account. or we could use APEX Sharing to get around this.

Special thanks to Geoffrey on Salesforce Success community for this solution:

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000Cl5kAAC